# Population selection for sensitivity and specificity

Tags: sensitivity-specificity

For medical physical assessment sensitivity and specificity is commonly used to assess the clinical relevance of the test. I'm specifically referring to manual medicine here, with orthopedic tests of ligaments, joints, bones, muscle tissue and arterial and nerve tests.

When these tests are presented in books, lecture material for students, blogs, youtube videos, and so on,  it's rare to include the population sample on which the tests were assessed. Prevalence of the condition in the group or in the population as a whole is often omitted as well. This seems like a big issue as specificity and sensitivity is often in the 20-80% range with a prevalence rate of less than a few percent.

When determining sensitivity and specificity of medical tests is there a consensus of what type of population sample to use?

Obviously you only assess the shoulder if a patient is experiencing problems in the region, would that also be the case for the study in which sensitivity and specificity was determined?

I hope this question is clear enough for this community, but I'll reiterate:
Is sensitivity and specificity measured on a normal healthy population or a population that was already screened for relevant problems?

Thanks.